# What Causes "The payload was invalid" Error in .Net Core 3.1 Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-protection

We have a .Net Core 3.1 web app that uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection version 3.1.0 to encrypt and decrypt data. The application all of the sudden fails to decrypt the data because of the error "The payload was invalid" as seen below:

```
[2021-08-18 08:12:19 ERR] [FoxCentral.Web.Api.ErrorController] Path: /api/botflows/2. Error: The payload was invalid.
Trace: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte* pbCiphertext, UInt32 cbCiphertext, Byte* pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, UInt32 cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 ciphertext, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
```

We store the keys in a database using Entity Framework Core and use X509 certificates to protect the keys. Below is how we set up data protection in our app:

```
var protectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection();

protectionBuilder.PersistKeysToDbContext<KeysContext>();

protectionBuilder.ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificates.KeyProtectCertificate)
.UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate(certificates.KeyUnprotectCertificates.ToArray());
```

All the data was encrypted and decrypted on the same server. What causes that decryption failure? How to recover the data?

Comment: Can you clarify in your question, does "all of a sudden" mean that without code change new behavior appeared when on this server you have been able to successfully both encrypt and decrypt the data in the past  Is it all data that will no longer decrypt?  Or only newly encrypted data?

Comment: Yep. The customer restarted the application and all of the sudden the old data could not be decrypted.

Comment: @tytra I would guess a framework update changed the process. Chances are too it was not a recent one, but one that has been waiting for a restart to take effect years now.

Comment: @Christopher The .Net Core version is the same - 3.1.0. The Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection version is still 3.1.0 and was not changed. I found this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-the-payload/ba-p/1919096. The author mentioned that setting the application name could be the fix. However, the keys repo is used by only one application and has been on the same server since day one. I'm not sure why setting the application name would fix that error. The more important question is how to recover the data.

Comment: Can you show more details how to create  `provider.CreateProtector` ?

Comment: Yep. This is how I create the protector.
`this.protector = protector.CreateProtector(nameof(EncryptedFileService));`

Answer (score 1):

I found [keys have a 90-day lifetime by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-5.0#key-lifetime) that why you cause the problem.

And I suggest you use `IKeyManager` to generate a new key, it maybe can help you recover data.

**Offical doc:**

[Automatic key ring refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-key-ring-refresh)

Comment: Why is using the default key lifetime is the problem?

Comment: @tytra I think there should be a problem with the code in the update key part, which caused this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;


services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("ProjectName")
            .AddKeyManagementOptions(options =>
            {
                options.NewKeyLifetime = new TimeSpan(180, 0, 0, 0);
                options.AutoGenerateKeys = true;
            });
```